# Perl Autovivication Use case

Tags: perl

I came across this piece of code (modified excerpt):

```
 my $respMap;
 my $respIdArray;
 foreach my $respId (@$someList) {
      push(@$respIdArray, $respId);
 }
 $respMap->{'ids'} = $respIdArray;
 return $respMap;
```

Is there a reason to use autovivication in this case? Why not simply do

```
 my $respMap;
 my @respIdArray;
 foreach my $respId (@$someList) {
      push(@respIdArray, $respId);
 }
 $respMap->{'ids'} = \@respIdArray;
 return $respMap;
```

Follow up: Could someone give me a good use case of autovivication?

Comment: Your rewrite introduces a subtle difference when `@$someList` is empty.  Also, I'm curious why you rewrote only the implicit arrayref allocation, but not the implicit hashref allocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either way is correct; first one using array reference `$respIdArray`, and second plain array `@respIdArray`. You'll need array references when building complex data structures (check `perldoc perlreftut`), but other than that it's up to you which one you'll choose.

Note that in both cases you're assigning array reference to `$respMap->{'ids'}`, so examples are actually pretty similar.

And btw, autovivification is another thing and has to do with dynamic creation of data structures.

Answer (score 1):

Autovivication is more useful when dealing with deep structures.

```
push( @{$hash{'key'}{$subkey}}, 'value' );
```